# With EN/HE layout, why do the arrow keys switch from logical to visual with Ctrl down?

Tags: gtk, lxde, text, cursor, right-to-left

I type in both Hebrew and English. When I use the Windows Manager's dialogs, or a GUI text editor such as leafpad, and type Hebrew text, I find the horizontal arrow keys (<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> and <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>) behave as follows:

- With no key down, cursor movement with the keys is logical movement, i.e. from earlier-typed characters to later-typed characters.
- With <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed, selection-and-movement is also in the logical order.
- With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed, word-length movement is *visual*, i.e. left arrow moves to the left, right arrow to the right.

Now, with English text this all amounts to the same thing, but in Hebrew, the visual and the logical order are opposites (ignoring certain caveats, BiDi is complicated). So I'm getting confusing and inconsistent keyboard behavior.

On the other hand, this doesn't happen with, say, LibreOffice.

Why is this happening? Is this a bug in some GTK+ text rendering mechanism? Is it something I've configured wrong? Some other problem?

**Notes:**

- My distribution is Lubuntu 15.04 (with LXDE as the window manager).
- My keyboard layout is:

  ```
  xkb_keymap {
      xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
      xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
      xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
      xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+il:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"};
      xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
  };
  ```